# Wait for multiple events from different modules and then start the server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redis

I'm building an app in which I have 2 different modules.One of them is the connection to mongodb and the other module is the connection to redis for session management. Each module has 2 events in this case error and connect.
Here is an example from one of the modules:

```
var sessionStore = new SessionStore(app.get("sessionStore"));

sessionStore.client.on("error", function(err) {

    console.error("[SessionStore]:", "connection error:", err.address + ":" + err.port, "for process:", process.pid);

    var sessionStoreError = new Error("Session store error");
    sessionStoreError.message = "Session store connection error";
    sessionStoreError.code = err.code;
    sessionStoreError.address = err.address;
    sessionStoreError.port = err.port;

    app.emit("error", sessionStoreError);

});


sessionStore.client.on("connect", function() {

    console.log("[SessionStore]:", "connection established:", app.get("sessionStore").host + ":" + app.get("sessionStore"), "for process:", process.pid);
    app.emit("ready");

});
```

Almost same way happens with mongodb module.

What I would like to achieve (avoiding the pyramid of doom) is something like this but when both redis and mongodb connections from their modules is successful:

```
app.on("ready", function(){
    app.listen(app.get("port")); 
});
```

Keep in mind that I could nest each module inside the other and perhaps require sequentialy the modules inside the connect handlers and then emit a final event to app, but this is not elegant I suppose according to my tastes that is.

Is there any elegant way to wait for 2 events and then start the server ?

Comment: You should check Promises, and wait for all promises using Promise.all(promisesArray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bootable`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/bootable) provides an initialization layer that you can also use for Express apps. This doesn't strictly provide a solution to your question (*"wait for 2 events"*), but it does solve the issue of waiting for multiple asynchronous modules before starting the server.

You can add boot phases for MongoDB and Redis. Once all phases are ready, the callback to `app.boot()` is called (you can check for any initialization errors there) and when everything is okay, the app can start listening for incoming connections.

Here's your session store example turned into a boot phase:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.phase(function(done) {
    var sessionStore = new SessionStore(app.get("sessionStore"));

    sessionStore.client.once("error", function(err) {
      console.error("[SessionStore]:", "connection error:", err.address + ":" + err.port, "for process:", process.pid);

      var sessionStoreError = new Error("Session store error");
      sessionStoreError.message = "Session store connection error";
      sessionStoreError.code = err.code;
      sessionStoreError.address = err.address;
      sessionStoreError.port = err.port;

      return done(sessionStoreError);
    });

    sessionStore.client.once("connect", function() {
      console.log("[SessionStore]:", "connection established:", app.get("sessionStore").host + ":" + app.get("sessionStore"), "for process:", process.pid);
      return done();
    });
  });
};
```

Your main code would look something like this:

```
var bootable = require('bootable');
var express  = require('express')
var app      = bootable(express());

require('./boot/session-store')(app); // loads the module above
require('./boot/mongodb')(app);       // a MongoDB boot phase

// This is the equivalent of your `app.on('ready', ...)`
app.boot(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  app.listen(app.get("port"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head, Here is the best solution I could think of:

I think the most "elegant" way is, like you suggested, to call each module with async.waterfall, and when both of them are done, send an event to the app. I think this is a good solution but the only problem with it is that you are losing time by activating the module sequentialy and not in the same time.

To save time, maybe you can use a less "elegant" solution like this:

The redis module will emit an event called "redisReady" and the mongoDb module will emit one called "mongoReady", and in the main module there will be:

```
app.on("redisReady", function(){
    redisModuleReady = true;
    if (mongoModuleReady) {
       app.listen(app.get("port"));  
    }
});

app.on("mongoReady", function(){
    mongoModuleReady = true;
    if (redisModuleReady) {
       app.listen(app.get("port"));  
    }
});
```

This is much less "pretty" but saves time.

Surely there are more solutions, but this is what I came up with.

Comment: Yea I was thinking something like that too, it's sad tho that there is a built in method in Eventemitter from multiple events like this case

Comment: You`re right, I`ve searched and nothing came up, although this is a reasonable feature. If there isn`t something I`ve missed, I think my answer is the best way to go.